# Cannot obtain value of local or argument possibly because it has been optimized away

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, service

I am making a call to a service reference

```
using (FeeService.FeeSvcClient svc = new FeeService.FeeClient())
            {
                response = svc.Retrieve(arg);
            }
```

However when debugging from the FeeService side, the arg parameter becomes

*"Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'args' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.*"

but the value is really null when it was passed a two letter code. This is the definition.

```
public void Retrieve(Dictionary<string, string> arg, out string docVariables)
        {
            if (null != _calc)
                _calc = null;

            docVariables = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_stateAbbreviation) == false)
            {
                string transType = "", vehClass = "", vehUse = "", dealType = "", purchaseStateCode = "";
                arg.TryGetValue("StateCode", out purchaseStateCode);
                arg.TryGetValue("trans", out transType);
                arg.TryGetValue("Class", out vehClass);
                arg.TryGetValue("Use", out vehUse);
                arg.TryGetValue("deal", out dealType);

                docVariables = Utility.GetDocument(_stateAbbreviation, transType, vehClass, vehUse, dealType, purchaseStateCode); 
            }

        }
```

I have tried all six methods to turn off optimized code:

```
   1. Checking off the optimized code in the build tab for project   
properties.
   2. Setting debug info mode to full in advance option of the build tab. 
   3. Turning off Visual Studio hosting process in the debug tab
   4. Checking if the active solution configuration is in debug and not release.
   5. Clean and rebuilt the solution.
   6. Doesn't appear I can check if the module is optimized since this is a service reference.
```